# Using Distributed Cache programmatically. "Cache referred to does not exist" error

Tags: 2013, development, cache

I'm trying to take advantage of Distributed Cache in SharePoint 2013 programmatically from a console application. I want to store custom objecst inside App Fabric Cache.

Here is the code that throws an error:

```
List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>();
servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("Myserver.domain", 22233));
DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
configuration.ChannelOpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
configuration.IsCompressionEnabled = false;
configuration.MaxConnectionsToServer = 10;
configuration.RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
configuration.Servers = servers;
configuration.TransportProperties.MaxBufferSize = 200000;
DataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);
DataCache cache = dataCacheFactory.GetDefaultCache(); // <---- Error
```

dataCacheFactory.GetDefaultCache() throws an error:

> Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the
>   Cache administration tool to create a Cache.

**Addtitional info:**

Distributed cache is running on my only development server

Get-CacheHostConfig command returns:

```
HostName        : {hostname}
ClusterPort     : 22234
CachePort       : 22233
ArbitrationPort : 22235
ReplicationPort : 22236
Size            : 410 MB
ServiceName     : AppFabricCachingService
HighWatermark   : 99%
LowWatermark    : 90%
IsLeadHost      : True
```

Get-CacheHost command returns:

```
HostName : CachePort               Service Name            Service Status Version Info
--------------------               ------------            -------------- ------------
{hostname}:22233                   AppFabricCachingService UP             3 [3,3][1,3]
```

I've  run this powershell comamnd against my current login:

```
Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount domain\user
```

I would be really grateful if someone could shed some light on this problem. Why do I get this error? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

*Update*

I've tried the same code on a completely different SharePoint Farm. There is the same error. So, it's not server-specific. I've managed to make this code work by getting the Cache by the full name like so:

```
DataCache cache = dataCacheFactory.GetCache("DistributedDefaultCache_bbc9d9fe-ea79-477a-890c-867b1ae0c91b");
```

You can get the full name by running this PowerShell command:

```
Get-Cache |Where-Object{$_.CacheName -like "*Default*"}|fl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the internal implementation of GetDefaultCache method looks like:

```
public DataCache GetDefaultCache()
{
  string cacheName = "default";
  return this.GetCache(cacheName);
}
```

It's just trying to call GetCache("defaul"). 'default' cache just does not exist. The real name of the default cache should look more like:

> DistributedDefaultCache_bbc9d9fe-ea79-477a-890c-867b1ae0c91b

This GUID turns out to be a farm ID.

So, this is an example that works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>();
        servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("server.domain", 22233));
        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
        configuration.ChannelOpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        configuration.IsCompressionEnabled = false;
        configuration.MaxConnectionsToServer = 10;
        configuration.RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        configuration.Servers = servers;
        configuration.TransportProperties.MaxBufferSize = 1000000;
        DataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);
        DataCache cache = dataCacheFactory.GetCache("DistributedDefaultCache_" + SPFarm.Local.Id);

        if (cache.Get("MyKEY") == null)
        {
            cache.Add("MyKEY", DateTime.Now);
        }
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)cache.Get("MyKEY");
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
```

**Important Update**

I've found that [you can't use default App Fabric cluster](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219572.aspx#Important) that is installed with prerequisites. Looks like it's unsupported by Microsoft.

> Do not use the AppFabric cache cluster supporting your SharePoint
>   Server 2013 farm. Run your separate AppFabric cache cluster for your
>   custom applications on separate servers from the servers dedicated to
>   your SharePoint Server 2013 farm.

What a shame!

Answer (score 1):

i would try to repair the DC:

1)  Get-SPServiceInstance cmdlet to list all services on all servers in the server farm
2) start the powershell  and run below command:

```
$s = Get-SPServiceInstance GUID
```

`$s.delete()`

3) wait for couple of min and in the powershell window run below command.

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Now try and if it fix fine.
[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx#repair)
2nd option is try to clear the config cache.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've properly cleared the config cache. Also, I've recreated Distributed Cache Application Instance with these commands: Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance.
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance.
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance. I still have the same error "Cache referred to does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

How to use SharePoint 2013’s AppFabric caching in your code

```
public sealed class CacheManager
    {
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();
        private static DataCache _defaultCache;

        private CacheManager() {}

        public static DataCache DefaultCache
        {
            get
            {
                using (SPMonitoredScope scope = new SPMonitoredScope("CacheManager.DefaultCache"))
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        if (_defaultCache == null)
                        {
                            //By default the farm ID is appended to the name of the cluster and caches
                            //created by SharePoint.
                            var farmID = SPFarm.Local.Id;

                            //This is one of the caches created by SharePoint. Run the AppFabric's
                            //Get-Cache PowerShell to see a list of caches created by SharePoint.
                            var defaultCacheName = "DistributedDefaultCache_" + farmID;

                            var factoryConfiguration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration()
                            {
                                Servers = GetAllDataCacheServerEndpointsForFarm(farmID)
                            };

                            _defaultCache = new DataCacheFactory(factoryConfiguration).GetCache(defaultCacheName);
                        }
                        return _defaultCache;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> GetAllDataCacheServerEndpointsForFarm(Guid farmID)
        {
            var endpoints = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>();

            //By default this is the name of the cluster created by SharePoint.
            string cacheClusterName = "SPDistributedCacheCluster_" + farmID;

            var cacheClusterManager = SPDistributedCacheClusterInfoManager.Local;
            var cacheClusterInfo = cacheClusterManager.GetSPDistributedCacheClusterInfo(cacheClusterName);

            foreach (var cacheHost in cacheClusterInfo.CacheHostsInfoCollection)
            {
                endpoints.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint(cacheHost.HostName, cacheHost.CachePort));
            }
            return endpoints;
        }
    }
```

https://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/01/03/how-to-use-sharepoints-2013-appfabric-caching-in-your-code/